# Empty form with for statement

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, for-loop

I have a `for` statement to create 20 number of forms, but after creating elements my forms look like empty(but I have input elements on it) and that is why I cannot send objects with POST.

```
<form method="post" ></form>
```

this is my code :

```
for($i= 1 ; $i<=$numtest ; $i++){
        $mdata = $numtoword->ToWordFa($i);
        echo '
            <li>
                <div class="questitle2 noselect"><a href="#">عنوان سوال '.$mdata.'</a></div>
                <div class="quescontent">
                    <input type="text" class="questitle byekan" name="tt'.$i.'" id ="tt'.$i.'" placeholder="عنوان سوال '.$i.'" onclick="select()" /><br/>
                    <div style="text-align:right;margin-top:10px;" class="qkind">نوع سوال :
                                <input type="radio" name="istest'.$i.'" id="is2test'.$i.'" value="yt2" onclick="add_choice(\'c'.$i.'\' , \'yt2\');" /><label for="is2test'.$i.'"><span class="noselect fade"> 2 گزینه ای</span></label>
                                <input type="radio" name="istest'.$i.'" id="is4test'.$i.'" value="yt4" onclick="add_choice(\'c'.$i.'\' , \'yt4\');" /><label for="is4test'.$i.'"><span class="noselect fade"> 4 گزینه ای</span></label>
                                <input type="radio" name="istest'.$i.'" id="nottest'.$i.'" value="nt2" onclick="add_choice(\'c'.$i.'\' , \'nt2\');"/><label for="nottest'.$i.'"><span class="noselect fade"> تـشریحی</span></label>
                    </div> 
                    <form method="post" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="tid1" value="'.$tkey.'"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="thisquestion1" value="'.$i.'"/>
                        <div class="choosepart" id="c'.$i.'"></div>
                        <div id="res"> </div>
                        <input class="fade" id="sc'.$i.'" style="margin-top:5px;" type="button" name="Send" onclick="formget( this.form  , \'tests.php\' , \'res\' , \'dd\' ,\''.$i.'\');" value="ثبت این سوال" disabled/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </li>
        ';
    }
```

Ajax will put input elements in this div of above code :

```
<div class="choosepart" id="c'.$i.'"></div>
```

how can moderate that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `::` you are trying to access a method statically so your function signature should be declared as: `public static function toWord2()`.

I think you defined your method `toWord2` as non-static and you are trying to invoke it as static. That said.

**1)** If you want to invoke a static method, you should use the `::` and define your method as static.

```
// Defining a static method in a Foo class.
public static function toWord2() { /* code */ }

// Invoking that static method
NumericHelper::toWord2();
```

**2)** otherwise, if you want to invoke an instance method you should instance your class, use `->`.

```
// Defining a non-static method in a Foo class.

    public function toWord2() { /* code */ }

    // Invoking that non-static method.
    $objNumericHelper = new NumericHelper();
    $objNumericHelper->toWord2();
```

You can ride same thing [about OOP & static methods in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: Thank you, I correct it , now there is no error and my form in still empty !!

Comment: My pleasure! Feel free to contact if any relative query/concern.

Answer (score 0):

Please place below code after `for` statement, this code will tell you what/where is the issue/error. Let me know if require more help from us.

```
//This code will suggest what/where is the error

print("<pre>");
print_r(error_get_last());
print("</pre>");
```

Hope this helps you.

Thanks!

Comment: thank you man , I add the code and output this :  Array
(
    [type] => 2048
    [message] => Non-static method NumericHelper::toWord2() should not be called statically
    [file] => /home/cp18276/public_html/miniworks/2/include/classes.php
    [line] => 130
)